# Accessing Facebook data through the Facebook Graph API and restFB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

When I access Facebook through the Graph API I get only very few entries. For instance if I access the Galaxy S4 fan page through the Graph API I see only four entries:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/412437702197294/comments/
```

if I access it through restFB I only get 2:

```
FacebookClient publicOnlyFacebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient();
Page page = publicOnlyFacebookClient.fetchObject("GalaxySFour", Page.class);

JsonObject galaxySFourID = publicOnlyFacebookClient.fetchObject("GalaxySFOUR", JsonObject.class);

JsonObject galaxySFour = publicOnlyFacebookClient.fetchObject(galaxySFourID.getString("cover_id") + "/comments", JsonObject.class);
Vector<String> comments = new Vector<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < galaxySFour.length(); i++) {
    comments.add("Message: " +            galaxySFour.getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(i).getString("created_time") + ": " + galaxySFour.getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(i).getString("message"));
}
```

I'm aware that I cannot get all data, but I didn't expect to get so little. Is there anyway to get more data?

Answer (score 2):

Access via this link : **http://facebook.com/412437702197294**,

there are only 4 comments. So, **https://graph.facebook.com/412437702197294/comments/** return 4 comments is right.

By default, when retrieving data via Facebook Graph API, you only get **20 results**.
You can use limit to get more data, such as:

```
http://facebook.com/412437702197294?limit=500
```

The maximum limit is **5000**.